# Matplotlib basemap multiple shapes animation exception: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_animated'

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using basemap to plot some polygons on a map and make an animation. When I animate one polygon and change its shape it works.
If I add second one I got exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 216, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 953, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1741, in _init_draw
    a.set_animated(self._blit)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_animated'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 216, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1269, in _handle_resize
    self._init_draw()
  File "..\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1741, in _init_draw
    a.set_animated(self._blit)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_animated'
```

My code:

```py
input = pd.read_csv(filename)
data = pd.read_csv(datafilename)


m = Basemap(projection='spstere',boundinglat=-50,lon_0=0,resolution='l', area_thresh = 1000.0)
m.fillcontinents()
m.drawmapboundary()
lon =[]
lat = []
lon1=[]
lat1=[]
for j in range(0,100):
    latlist = list()
    latlist1 = list()
    for i in range(0,361):
        latlist.append(float(input.iloc[j][str(i)]))
        latlist1.append(float(data.iloc[j][str(i)]))
    lat.append(latlist)
    lon.append(list(range(0,361)))
    lat1.append(latlist1)
    lon1.append(list(range(0,361)))
polys = []

x,y = m(lon[0],lat[0])
xy = list(zip(x,y))
poly=Polygon(xy,facecolor='None', alpha=1, edgecolor='green', linewidth=1)

x1,y1 = m(lon1[0],lat1[0])
xy1 = list(zip(x1,y1))
poly1=Polygon(xy1,facecolor='None', alpha=1, edgecolor='red', linewidth=1)

polys.append(poly)
polys.append(poly1)
def init():
    plt.gca().add_patch(polys[0])
    plt.gca().add_patch(polys[1])
    return polys,

def animate(i):
    print(i)
    x,y = m(lon[i], lat[i])
    xy=list(zip(x,y))
    polys[0].set_xy(xy)

    x1,y1 = m(lon1[i], lat1[i])
    xy1=list(zip(x1,y1))
    polys[1].set_xy(xy1)
    return polys,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, init_func=init, frames=100, interval=500, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

If I return only one poly in functions and set blit=False it works. 
If I return only one poly in functions and blit=True - only one polygon changes. How to animate two shapes in one animation with blitting?

Comment: Note for anyone who encountered this error and this question wasn't quite what they needed: `Axes.plot` returns a _list_ of `Artist` objects. So if you're invoking `.plot` multiple times, you need to chain the results together or otherwise flatten them to a single list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return an *iterable of artists* that you want to be updated. That is usually a tuple or list.

`polys` is a list of artists
`poly, poly1` is a tuple of artists
`[poly, poly1]` is a list of artists
`(poly, poly1)` is a tuple of artists
etc.

But `polys,` is a tuple of one list. That one list is not an artist, which is what the error tells you.

Comment: why `polys,` is not an artist?